# Exam preparation: logic - problems on (maximally) consistent sets

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am preparing for an exam on aspects of Logic related to propositional and first order logic.  One of my revision exam questions is [image: exam question].  I have attempted this question but I am really struggling with all parts of the question.  If anyone could provide any hints or suggestions then I would be very grateful.  My current (attempt) at a solution is:
[image: Question 4a]
[image: Question 4c]

Please note that for (a) I am suspicious of my proof because -> elimination is not used anywhere, for (b) my work hasn't progressed much beyond writing the definitions in the proof, and (c), I am struggling with the valuation extension.

Answer (score 0):

- For (a) your answer seems correct but you are missing the hypothesis side, in your notation, so I would write something more like:

$$ \{\alpha,\beta\} \vdash \alpha \qquad \mathrm{given}
\\ \{\alpha\} \vdash \beta \to \alpha \qquad \mathrm{insertion}
\\ \emptyset \vdash \alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha) \qquad \mathrm{insertion}$$

and since $\emptyset\subseteq\Sigma$ for all $\Sigma$, and inclusion preserves derivability, $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$ for all $\Sigma$

- For (b) just do, if $\Sigma$ is maximally consistent and $\Sigma\not\vdash\alpha$, then
  $$ \Sigma \cup \{\alpha\} \vdash \alpha\to(\alpha\to\beta) $$
  and so, by elimination you get $\Sigma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$
- Finally, for (c) you just start to define the valuation on your base cases $v(\phi)$ when $\phi\in X$, in which case you define $v(\phi) = \top $ if $\phi \in X\cap \Sigma$ and $v(\phi) = \bot$ if $\phi \in X\setminus \Sigma$ finally you define the recursion for formulae of the form $\phi\to\psi$ where you define $v(\phi\to\psi)=\top$ if $\phi\to\psi\in\Sigma$ and $v(\phi\to\psi)=(\lnot v(\phi))\lor v(\psi)$ otherwise.

To check that this valuation obeys the necessary precepts, you just need to show that the recursive step preserves the valuation when you do introduction and elimination, since by definition it already does so for insertion.

Comment: Your second part is wrong because your first part was wrong. I've corrected the first part.

Comment: thanks, such are the dangers of copy-paste :p

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. Can I clarify a couple of things? 1. For part (a) are you saying the amendments you have added should come after the proof to explain the method? 2. For (b) I am struggling to see how taking a maximally consistent set means you can write the first line: Sigma U {alpha} ... Would you be able to clarify these please?

Comment: the only thing I did on (a) was to insert the set of base formulae on the left, from which the formula on the right can be derived by meansof the rule on the far-right...

Comment: as for (b), since $\Sigma$ is maximally consistent and $\alpha \notin \Sigma$, by definition any $\Sigma\cup\{\alpha\}\vdash \phi$ for *any* formula $\phi$, this is true in particular for $\phi = \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$